# Spring dynamic autowire services

Tags: spring, autowired

I've started to build some kind of a CMS and I'm stuck over one idea.

The description is:

I have standard MVC Controller (Home) in which I'm downoading modules settings which will be set in this Controller.

The response is, that I have to implement module with name "HPModule".

So I'm trying to load this module by `Class.forName("com.app.something.HPModule");` and then call method `init();`

My HPModule is:

```
public class HPModule
{

    @Resource(name = "hpModuleService")
    private HPModuleService hpModuleService;

    public String init()
    {
        SomeObject someObject = hpModuleService.getArticle();
    }
}
```

And I found that when I'm trying to do `SomeObject someObject = hpModuleService.getArticle();` Spring is blind for `@Resource` when I'm calling class by `Class.forName`.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The `HPModule` has to be a Spring Bean retrieved by means of `DI` or directly from Spring `BeanFactory`. You cannot expect Spring to autowire a class that is not instantiated by Spring, unless You use `@Configurable` and `AspectJ` to weave the class.

If `HPModule` already is a Spring Bean, than just `@Autowire` or `@Inject` it directly into the MVC controller that needs it.

If You don't know in compile time what modules You'll need, than inject `ListableBeanFactory` and use `BeanFactoryUtils` to get the modules You need in runtime by type or by name.

Comment: Do you know some goot tutorials with using BeanFactoryUtils ?

Comment: `BenFactoryUtils` is only a few static methods to retrieve beans from `ListableBeanFactory` more conveniently - just read the JavaDoc to see what each method does if can't figure it out be the name itself.